# get json object count for same year using jquery and group it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i want get the total count in each year from this row data

```
var users = [
  { name: "John", address: "USA", year: 2010 },
  { name: "jjj", address: "USA", year: 2011 },
  { name: "rrrr", address: "USA", year: 2012 },
  { name: "hhh", address: "USA", year: 2013 },
  { name: "fff", address: "USA", year: 2011 },
  { name: "Joffhn", address: "USA", year: 2012 },
  { name: "dd", address: "USA", year: 2013 },
  { name: "dddd", address: "USA", year: 2014 },
  { name: "ss", address: "USA", year: 2012 },
  { name: "hh", address: "USA", year: 2013 },
  { name: "yyy", address: "USA", year: 2014 }
];
```

expected result is,

```
var result = [
  { year: 2010, count: 1 },
  { year: 2011, count: 2 },
  { year: 2012, count: 3 },
  { year: 2013, count: 3 },
  { year: 2014, count: 2 }
];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

I've written this algorithm to extract the mappings you want:

First we map each year to how many times it appears in the first array:

```
const mapCounts = users.reduce(function(acc, el) {
   acc[el.year] = acc[el.year] ? ++acc[el.year] : 1;
   return acc;
}, {});
```

Then we transform that object into an array containing `{ year, count }` like elements:

```
const arrayWithCounts = Object.keys(mapCounts).map(el => ({ year: el, count: mapCounts[el] }));
```

putting it all together in a function:

```
function getMappedYearCounts(arr) {
  const mapCounts = users.reduce(function(acc, el) {
    acc[el.year] = acc[el.year] ? ++acc[el.year] : 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const resultArr = Object.keys(mapCounts).map(el => ({
    year: el,
    count: mapCounts[el]
  }));

  return resultArr;
}
```

Comment: so `var result = Object.entries(users.reduce((r, {year}) => (r[year] = (r[year] || 0) + 1, r), {})).map(([year, count]) => ({year, count}));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy` and create the desired count array like this,

```js
 var users = [
 {name: 'John',address: 'USA',year:2010 }, {name: 'jjj',address: 'USA',year:2011 }, {name: 'rrrr',address: 'USA',year:2012 }, {name: 'hhh',address: 'USA',year:2013 }, {name: 'fff',address: 'USA',year:2011 }, {name: 'Joffhn',address: 'USA',year:2012 }, {name: 'dd',address: 'USA',year:2013 }, {name: 'dddd',address: 'USA',year:2014 }, {name: 'ss',address: 'USA',year:2012 }, {name: 'hh',address: 'USA',year:2013 }, {name: 'yyy',address: 'USA',year:2014 }];
 
function groupByYear (arr) {
    var groupBy = {};
    $.each(arr, function () {
        groupBy[this.year] = 1 + (groupBy[this.year] || 0);
    });
    return groupBy;
}

function createArray(obj){
    var arr = [];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
        arr.push({
            year: key,
            count:obj[key]
        });        
    });
    return arr;
}

var resObj = groupByYear(users);
var resArray = createArray(resObj);
console.log(resArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```